# How to make a 3D histogram of a 2D vector distribution in python / plotly

Tags: python, 3d, statistics, plotly, visualization

So, basically I have a list of 2D vectors in python, and I want to make a 3d visualization of the distribution of this vector, like a surface curve, through plotly. I'll leave a sample of the first 4 components of my vector

`[[0.35431211986827776, 0.21438054570807566], [0.35431211986827776, 0.21438054570807566], [0.35431211986827776, 0.21438054570807566], [0.35431211986827776, 0.21438054570807566],`

so I used the `seaborn.kdeplot()` to visualize, giving only the 2D visualization of the KDE:

[image: KDE estimator for bivariate sample]

But i wanted a 3D result, like in this bivariate normal distribution plot, where de X and Y axis are a 2d matrix and the z axis the pdf:

[image]

I think I just need to find a good pdf estimate for each vector in my list. Is there a way to fit a KDE to my data, in order to obtain this approximated distribution of each vector an then plot the surface?

Many thanks

Comment: Could you provide the full data somewhere, so one can try to play with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way to do that:

```
x = np.random.normal(5, 10, 100000)
y = np.random.normal(10, 3, 100000)
h = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=50)

def bin_centers(bins):
    centers = (bins + (bins[1]-bins[0])/2) [:-1]    
    return centers

x_bins_centers = bin_centers(h[1])
y_bins_centers = bin_centers(h[2])

df = pd.DataFrame(h[0], index=x_bins_centers, columns=y_bins_centers)
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Surface(z=df)])
fig.show()
```

The result is:

[image]

Comment: Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: My pleasure. It would be great if you could accept the answer :)